# In my c code when I'm printing k its printing -4 but its have to be -3 ?

Tags: c

You can see that in my code I just write `int` k and and its printing `k`=-4. why not -3 because `k` is an integer so it will store -3 from -3.53.

```
{
int a,b,c,k;
int *x, *y, *z;
a=10, b=15, c=-5;
x = &a;
y =  &b;
z= &c;
*z= *z +1;
*x = *x + (-2);
k = ((*z)++) - ((*x) / (*y));
printf("%d %d %d %d",*x, c, *z, k);
}
```

Comment: `(*x) / (*y)` is *integer arithmetic*. There is never a `-3.53`.

Comment: Next question you ask you should post your code as a [mre]

Comment: i think its for z++. if you use ++z its 3 but when you use z++ its 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a print just before the interresting line - like:

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", *z, *x, *y);
k = ((*z)++) - ((*x) / (*y));
```

Output:

```
-4 8 15
```

Since `*x` is less than `*y` the integer division `((*x) / (*y))` will give zero. So the calculation is just:

```
k = ((*z)++)
```

Here the `++` is a **post** increment of `*z`. That is: the value of `*z` is returned and **afterwards** `*z` will be incremented. Therefore `k` will get the value `-4` and `*z` will become `-3`